# User specific global variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

my program looks as follows:

```
var globVar=[];

function1(usr){
   //calculations with globVar
}

function2(usr){
   //calculations with globVar
}

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var formString = req.body.filter1;
    globVar.push(formString);
    usr= req.connection.user;
    function1(usr);
    function2(usr);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

req.connection.user comes from  nodeSSPI module. I need to make this globVar user specific so it doesn't mixed up when users runs this app concurrently. Now it works well but only for single user :)

Thank you for your consideration on this matter.

Comment: I'm not a node guy, but can you not make `globVar` like `globVar = { users: [{id: 1, ...}, {id:2, ...}]}`

Comment: you can use `express-session` for this or any other session middleware.

Comment: Refer to this https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: Currently this globVar keeps state depending on user's  actions.
And all functions gives results depending on globVar . As far as I know session variable won't be avaliable in these functions? I need to keep the state of globVar.

Comment: @piska you can create an array inside post request and then pass that array into functions like `function1(usr, array)` and `function2(usr, array)` .  I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: my problem is I do not want to define  globVar  for every route as it's changes depending on user input and output in functions. I hope this makes sense. Thx for all suggestions so far

Comment: try use let statment

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions and conclusion is that I would need to put  var usr= req.connection.user from route as a global variable so all functions can see it. Thx for all help so far

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at what seems like the same problem and my solution was to simply use cookies, and set a variable within the cookies client-side.

In my case the problem was setting language choice permanently for each user and that was simplest.

This guide helps:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_cookies.htm